# How to make this image and text center and vertical-align of div?

Tags: html, css

```css
#confirm {
 background-color: #FFAE00;
 width:80%;
 height: 5em;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="confirm">
  <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/mdb6Noh.png">
  <span>Confirm</span>
</div>
```

How to make this image and text center and vertical-align of div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:flex` to parent div. and give `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` to make them center.

```css
#confirm {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #ffae00;
    display: flex;
    height: 5em;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="confirm">
  <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/mdb6Noh.png">
  <span>Confirm</span>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

You can use `display:inline-block` if you don't want to use `display:flex`.

```css
#confirm {
    background-color: #ffae00;
    height: 5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
}

img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="confirm">
  <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/mdb6Noh.png">
  <span>Confirm</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but any way not use flex?

Comment: @aBloomer check my edited answer. You can use `display:inline-block`. And `display:flex` works in all latest browser.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking to do this:

```
<style>
#confirm {
background-color: #FFAE00;
width:80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<div id="confirm">
<div style="clear:both; margin-right:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/mdb6Noh.png"></div>
<span>Confirm</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below CSS :

```css
 #confirm {
   background-color: #ffae00;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #confirm span{
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80%;
  }
  #confirm img{
     display: table-cell;
     float: left;
     margin-right: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="confirm">
  <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/mdb6Noh.png">
  <span>Confirm</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please use image as vertical align in middle in css rule

like

```
#confirm{
  text-align:center;
}
#confirm img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```